# select table 1 columns with reference from table 2

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, left-join, pivot-table

| RowID | A1 | A2 | A3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1.0 | 0.1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2.0 | 0.2 |

| Item Name | Cell location |
| --- | --- |
| Item1 | A1 |
| Item2 | A3 |
| Item3 | A2 |

How can I select table 1 columns with reference ItemName from table 2?

Final Table

| RowID | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.1 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.2 | 2.0 |

We tried with PIVOT on table 2 and LEFT JOIN.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: What are you after here, an SQL statement that fulfills the requirement? If so, this isn't a C# question.

Comment: And please show us what you tried.

Comment: Please add some samples of what you have tried so far. It is very unclear that whether this is a SQL kind of question or C# based question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data

```
Declare @t1 table(
   RowID INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,A1    float  NOT NULL
  ,A2    float NOT NULL
  ,A3    float NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @t1
  (RowID,A1,A2,A3) VALUES 
  (1,1,1.0,0.1),
  (2,2,2.0,0.2);

Declare @t2 table(
   Item_Name     VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL 
  ,Cell_location VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @t2(Item_Name,Cell_location) VALUES 
('Item1','A1'),
('Item2','A3'),
('Item3','A2');
```

what you need, first `Unpivot` first table and then `Join` it with second table and then use `Pivot` table

```
select 
  * 
from 
  (
    select 
      RowID, 
      Item_Name, 
      value 
    from 
      (
        select 
          RowID, 
          name, 
          value 
        from 
          @t1 unpivot (
            value for name in ([A1], [A2], [A3])
          ) unpiv
      ) a 
      join @t2 t2 on a.name = t2.Cell_location
  ) b pivot (
    sum(value) for Item_Name in ([Item1], [Item2], [Item3])
  ) piv;
```

[Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/evCm6aW7)